# How can I save user's image with their sign up credentials in the registration form? React native, Firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a simple registration form, the user enter some info  (email, phone number, password ... etc), this info gets saved in a firebase collection called "Doctors". I want users to upload a profile picture and I want it to be save in the same collection with user info when pressing the signup button.

Here's my registration code:

```
export class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
       this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        name: '', 
        lastname: '',
        degree: '',
        phonenumber:'',
        description:''
           }

    this.onSignUp = this.onSignUp.bind(this)
        }


  onSignUp(){

    if(
    this.state.email != '' &&
    this.state.password != '' &&
    this.state.name != '' &&
    this.state.lastname != '' 
    ){
     const { email, password, name, lastname, degree, phonenumber, description } = this.state;
     firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((result) => {
            firebase.firestore().collection("Doctors")
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set({
                    name,
                    email,
                    lastname,
                    degree,
                    phonenumber,
                    description
                })
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
         }
   else{
   alert("Make sure you filled all the fields with correct info!");
     }
    }
```

And Here's the image picker code:

```
  export default function ImagePickerExample() {
   const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

     useEffect(() => {
(async () => {
  if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
    const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      }
      }
    })();
  }, []);

const pickImage = async () => {
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 1,
});

console.log(result);

if (!result.cancelled) {
  setImage(result.uri);
}
```

};

Comment: Does the pickImage function return a blob or base64 string? To store images you would have to use Firebase Storage.  You can store base64 strings in Firesotre but I don't think that's a good idea as each doc has 1 MB limit. I can help with Storage 

Comment: Nope, I only created the picker. I'm still learning and saving images is really confusing to me at this point

Comment: Can you please share output of `console.log(result)` which is inside of pickImage function?

Comment: Object {
  "cancelled": false,
  "height": 785,
  "type": "image",
  "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/UNVERIFIED-192.168.43.69-Doctors/ImagePicker/8df9eeda-031d-4e79-b1e2-f22e0b553174.jpg",  
  "width": 1046,
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should use [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/products/storage) for saving images or files rather than Firestore. A single Firestore document has a limit of 1 MB so that might be insufficient even if you store the image as a base64 string.

**1: Get a base64 string from ImagePicker:**

```js
const pickImage = async () => {
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  base64: true,
  //      ^^^^
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 1,
});

const base64String = pickImage.base64
// This is your image in base64 format
// Store it in your state so you can access it while uploading to Firebase
```

**2. Uploading to Firebase Storage:**

```js
async onSignUp(){
  if (this.state.email != '' && this.state.password != '' && this.state.name != '' && this.state.lastname != '') {
    const { email, password, name, lastname, degree, phonenumber, description } = this.state;
    const userCredential = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    const {uid} = userCredential.user            
    const imageBase64String = "" // Get the base64string saved in state here
    await Promise.all([
      firebase.firestore()
        .collection("Doctors")
        .doc(uid)
        .set({name, email, lastname, degree, phonenumber, description}),
      firebase.storage()
        .ref('users/' + uid)
        .putString(imageBase64String.split(',')[1], "base64", {contentType: 'image/jpeg'})
    ])
 } else{
   alert("Make sure you filled all the fields with correct info!");
 }
}
```

I haven't used that image picker before. If you pass `base64: true` then it'll return base64 string for that image as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#arguments-2). It's totally upto you how you want to handle the state and get that base64 string in signup function. Also I made that function `async` for convenience. We run both the promises (adding doc to Firestore and uploading image to Firebase Storage) simultaneously using `Promise.all()`