# React Native FireStorage On Android

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I try to upload images on cloud storage (Firebase) which I am able to do on web but on android it not uploading it show this error:

[image: error]

and when I do it on web when I try to print image object it shows

[image]

the thing is it work on web without error but not on android. Here i updated my code as you said but now it not ever work android but on web too.
I try to change it to data_url and it work for web but for android it show error.
By the way on android it show a image path like..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NesdH.png) but web has a format of data:base64;

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";

//Firebase Storege..
import {
  ref,
  getDownloadURL,
  uploadString,
  deleteObject,
  uploadBytes,
} from "firebase/storage";
import { storage } from "../firebaseWeb";

import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

//Loader...
import * as Progress from "react-native-progress";

//ContextAPI....
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth";

const UploadImage = () => {
  const { userInfo, setProfileLink, profileLink } = useAuth();

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const removePicture = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    //Delete from Fibebase Storage...
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `profiles/${userInfo.uid}/profilePic`);

    deleteObject(imageRef)
      .then(() => {
        setProfileLink(null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      })
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  };

  const openImagePickerAsync = async () => {
    const permissionResult =
      await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      alert("Permission to access camera roll is required!");
      return;
    }

    const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      base64: true,
    });

    if (pickerResult.cancelled === true) {
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);

    //Upload to Fibebase Storage...
    const imageRef = ref(storage, `profiles/${userInfo.uid}/profilePic`);
    console.log(pickerResult.uri);

    await uploadString(imageRef, pickerResult.uri, "base64url")
      .then(async (snapshot) => {
        const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
        setProfileLink(downloadURL);
      })
      .catch((error) => alert(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  };

  if (profileLink !== null) {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={removePicture}>
          <Image
            source={{ uri: profileLink }}
            className="w-80 md:w-96 h-96"
            style={{
              resizeMode: "contain",
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  // if (loading)
  //   return (
  //     <View className="items-center justify-center">
  //       <Progress.Circle size={30} indeterminate={true} />
  //     </View>
  //   );

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      className="w-64 md:w-96 p-3 rounded-xl bg-red-400"
      onPress={openImagePickerAsync}
    >
      <Text className="text-center text-white text-xl">
        Pick A Profile Picture.
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default UploadImage;
```

See my `openImagePickerAsync` function.

Comment: Can you try using [base64](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickeroptions) string once? You can use `launchImageLibraryAsync({ base64: true })` so that'll return a `base64` string and then `uploadString(storageRef, 'BASE64_DATA', 'base64url')` For [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68572749/how-can-i-save-users-image-with-their-sign-up-credentials-in-the-registration-f).

Comment: No this is not working it still show same error.

Comment: Can you update the question with code that you've tried?

Comment: i updated my code and also i notice on android it show URL as file://... and on web it show URL like data:base64 ....

Comment: it's `pickerResult.base64` and not `.uri`.

Comment: It work on web but not on Android and IOS i looks like i get a base64 String but to upload it to Cloud Store i need to convert whole string as data://image/type;base64,..... i search online it say i need to use expo-image-manuplator to convert base64 string to base64 with data://image but documentation not show code here you can check by yourself https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator/